OS Security update on a VM where WSO2 API Manager is installed
Our client wants to update the OS on both Test and production VMS, and add the below security packages
The question here is if these packages could somehow affect the stable operation of the WSO2 APIM server
The current installation has the following info :
WSO2 Api Manager Version : Version 4.2.0
JVM Version : 17.0.7+7-adhoc.root.jdk17u
JVM Vendor  : OpenLogic
OS Name : Linux
OS Version : 4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64
Either way, we intend to perform tests after each VM installation. But any stated concern of yours will be helpfull
Thanks in advance
Below is the abovementioned list of packages
kernel
kernel-core
kernel-modules
kernel-tools
kernel-tools-libs
python3-perf
kernel-headers
sudo
python3-unbound
unbound-libs
curl
libcurl
less
expat
gnutls
bind-export-libs
bind-libs
bind-libs-lite
bind-license
bind-utils
python3-bind
glibc
glibc-all-langpacks
glibc-common
glibc-devel
glibc-gconv-extra
glibc-headers
shim-x64
qemu-guest-agent
libX11
libX11-common
python3-jinja2
squashfs-tools
iwl100-firmware
iwl1000-firmware
iwl105-firmware
iwl135-firmware
iwl2000-firmware
iwl2030-firmware
iwl3160-firmware
iwl5000-firmware
iwl5150-firmware
iwl6000-firmware
iwl6000g2a-firmware
iwl6050-firmware
iwl7260-firmware
linux-firmware
pam
openssh
openssh-clients
openssh-server
grub2-common
grub2-efi-x64
grub2-pc
grub2-pc-modules
grub2-tools
grub2-tools-extra
grub2-tools-minimal
systemd
systemd-libs
systemd-pam
systemd-udev
gmp
libssh
libssh-config
krb5-libs
libipa_hbac
libsss_autofs
libsss_certmap
libsss_idmap
libsss_nss_idmap
libsss_sudo
python3-sssdconfig
sssd
sssd-ad
sssd-client
sssd-common
sssd-common-pac
sssd-ipa
sssd-kcm
sssd-krb5
sssd-krb5-common
sssd-ldap
sssd-nfs-idmap
sssd-proxy
gdk-pixbuf2
platform-python
python3-libs
libxml2
python3-libxml2
cockpit
cockpit-bridge
cockpit-system
cockpit-ws

WSO2 API manager is independent of OS packages. So there shouldn't be a problem when upgrading the OS packages. But as you have mentioned, better to do this in a testing environment and proceed.
